# Elements are listed in a vob but not able to checkout/checkin in CCRC

Tags: client, clearcase-remote-client

There are 2 windows domains named as OPR & BDC. In OPR domain the CCRC server is hosted, users accessing from BDC domain can able to connect to CCRC and list the vob....and also able to join the project. To perform any checkout/checkin/loading resources it is taking long time and after a day it is in same state.Connectivity is fine to OPR domain from BDC domain ( ping & tracrt is working fine) .

Could you please let me know if you have some idea about it?

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: @Sunil: Glad to see you have it figured out. Could you edit your answer and put some details about what was causing the issue?

Comment: You can also ask for merging your two SO accounts (sunil devan and sunil)

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a credential issue.

You need to:

- check the user/group used for their web view (as an administrator, go in one of those snapshot web view, and try a '`cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`')
- check their local credential (`credmap registryServer`)

Basically, are those users known (declared) on the VOB server queried by your CCRC server?